# Creating a program that reads a file and returns the smallest variable and how many variables are in the file

Tags: python

I am creating a program on Python that reads a text file and prints the lowest variable and then prints however many variables are in the text file. I have gotten somewhat finished with it, however it is returning '0' when I run the program. I, too, want to create this with it catching IOError and ValueErrors. This is what I have so far:

`

```
smallest = 0

try:
    numbers = open('students.txt', 'r')

except ValueError:

    for line in numbers:
        clean_line = line.strip()
        split_line = clean_line.split('-')
        name = split_line[0]
        grade = int(split_line[1])

    if smallest >= grade:
        smallest = grade

print('Lowest score and student:', smallest)
```

`

The output is 'Lowest score and student: 0"

The file that I am working with contains the following:
Tom-87
Fred-63
Susan-95
Bart-93
Jacob-84
Mark-77
Venni-72
Tom-64
Don-91
Tonya-98
Larry-93
Leo-55
Lori-86
Jen-93

I tried the code and I got a '0' instead of the actual name and score.

UPDATE:

I have tried and tried if my indentations are off and for the most part I cannot tell.
This is the code I have now:

```
smallest = 0
try:
    numbers = open('students.txt', 'r')
    for line in numbers:
        clean_line = line.strip()
        split_line = clean_line.split('-')
        name = split_line[0]
        grade = int(split_line[1])
        if smallest >= grade:
            smallest = grade
    counter = len(numbers.readlines())
except ValueError:
    print('Error received.')
finally:
    print('Lowest score and student: ', smallest)
    print('Number of records: ', counter)
```

Comment: `if smallest >= grade:` and `smallest = grade` need to be indented one level deeper.

Comment: that gave me the same output.

Comment: The other problem is your working code is hidden in an `except ValueError:` block that will never be reached.

Comment: `smallest` starts out as zero.  The only way  `if smallest >= grade` would ever be true is if the file contains negative grades...

Comment: Changed that and that fixed that however, I need to get the name that is connected with that number in that file to print as well

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data on a dictionary and use *min()* to find the smallest value.

```
dict = {}

for line in numbers:
    ...
    dict[name] = grade  # {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
    
print(f'{min(dict)}: {dict[min(dict)]}') # Mark: 77
```

The **min()** function search the lowest value on the dict and return this key, that in this case, is the name of studdent (Mark). To access the grade, (value of key) you need to use *dict[key]*